# Xtext - Temporarily tolerate unresolvable references and make the reference name user readable

Tags: xtext, emf

Let's say I have a language that models a part of stackoverflow. Users are held in one resource, questions in another.

Users:

```
user fred : fred@foobar.com
user notfred : notfred@foobar.com
```

Questions:

```
question 123 by fred message "smart question"
question 124 by notfred message "not so smart question"
```

Now, the user "fred" wants to remove his account, but this wouldn't work because after loading both resources into my ResourceSet I would have a non-empty Resource#getErrors().

I can work around this by filtering XtextLinkingDiagnostic from the errors, but still other users reading the "smart question" cannot tell anymore that it was asked by someone called "fred". The info is still there, I can access it for example when I set a LinkingDiagnosticMessageProvider with LazyLinkingResource#setDiagnosticMessageProvider(...); however, the best thing I can now do is, show other users validation errors that "fred" was deleted, but they wouldn't know "fred" wrote the message they are just reading. Knowing this would help them a lot because everybody knows that "fred" writes great questions, right?

Long story short, I have an application into which users can load a declaration and a definition file. In very few cases something goes wrong and both files don't match perfectly, which means the definition has entries that are not declared in the declaration. However, I know that ~95% of the entries will still match!
Users cannot fix this quickly, but it is likely that they are happy just editing the 95% definitions, *but* they still need to be able to *read* the names of the 5% declarations without editing them!

I am not currently using any UI-parts of Xtext to edit the definitions, but rather a custom UI in form of a table. The current state with the missing declarations is that everything except a value column will be empty. The reference ID would be in another column, and knowing this ID would help the user a lot! Is there a clean way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you have a look at the 'Node Model'? e.g. `org.eclipse.xtext.nodemodel.util.NodeModelUtils.findNodesForFeature(EObject, EStructuralFeature)` allows you to access the text that is written in the file

Comment: Thanks @Christian, that's almost the complete answer to my question!
The only thing missing is the following call because I have registered a ValueConverter. lazyLinkingResource.getLinkingHelper().getCrossRefNodeAsString(node, true)
If you like, create an answer from your comment and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the 'Node Model' e.g. `org.eclipse.xtext.nodemodel.util.NodeModelUtils.findNodesForFeature(EObject, EStructuralFeature)` allows you to access the text that is written in the file